# How to show that the Riemannian metric is $d_s^{2}= d_r^{2}+r^{2}\sin^{2}\theta d_\varphi^{2}$

Tags: geometry, riemannian-geometry, riemann-integration, riemann-surfaces

[image]

Well, i am reading the book Elliptic Theory on singular manifolds, Vladimir E. Nazaikinskii
Anton Yu. Savin
Bert-Wolfgang Schulze
Boris Yu. Sternin,

The manifold is the cone  given by $x^{2}+y^{2}=z^{2}\sin^{2}\theta$, with $z\geq 0$, where $\theta$ is the angle between axis and the generator of the cone.
I am not expert in this subject, i am learning, so i try with the simple case, if i suppose that
we are workimg with $x^{2}+y^{2}=z^{2}$ then i put $f(x,y)=(x,y,\sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}})$. Hence, if i choose $x=r\cos\theta$ and $y=r\sin\theta$ hence

$dx=dr\cos\theta -r\sin\theta d\theta$

$dy= dr\sin\theta +r\cos\theta d\theta$

$dz=dr$

Then, when i compute $dx^{2}+dy^{2}+dz^{2}= 2dr^{2}+r^{2}d\theta^{2}$, but now, if i tried the same is turn complicate because $z=(\sin\theta)^{-1}\sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}}$ and $\varphi$ is the polar angle on the plane $xy$ and $r$ is the distance betweeen vertex and the point that i will choose in the cone. I did not understand the line $r^{2}=x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2}=(x^{2}+y^{2})(1+\sin^{2}\theta)$ above in the picture, is a mistake?

Please somebody can to help me or give me a hint please, i want to proof that

$d_s^{2}= d_r^{2}+r^{2}\sin^{2}\theta d_\varphi^{2}$.

After of the hint from Svyatoslav, i have my firs relation

$\sin\theta = \frac{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}{r}$, and $\cos\theta= \frac{z}{r}$. On the plane $xy$ i have
$\cos \varphi=\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$ and $\sin\varphi=\frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$, hence

$x=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}cos\varphi=r\sin\theta\cos\varphi$ and

$y=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}sin\varphi=r\sin\theta\sin\varphi$, now when i fix $\theta$ implies

$dx= \sin\theta (dr\cos\varphi -r\sin\varphi d\varphi)$,

$dy= \sin\theta(dr\sin\varphi + r\cos\varphi d\varphi)$. So,

$dx^2= \sin^2\theta(dr^2\cos^2\varphi  -2 rdrd\varphi\sin\varphi\cos\varphi + r^2\sin^2\varphi d\varphi^2)$,

$dy^2= \sin^2\theta(dr^2\sin^2\varphi + 2 rdrd\varphi\sin\varphi\cos\varphi + r^2\cos^2\varphi d\varphi^2 )$,

$dz^2=dr^2\cos^2\theta$, finally

$dx^2+dy^2+dz^2= dr^2 +r^2\sin^2\theta d\varphi^2$.

Comment: If you, at fixed $\phi$, change $r$, you will go on the cone perpendicular to the circle, and the element of length in this case is $ds=dr$ (because $\vec r$ simply lies on the cone. If you change at the same time $r$ and $\phi$, the element of length is $ds=\sqrt{\rho^2d\phi^2+dr^2}$, because going along the circle with radius $\rho$ (changing $\phi$ at fixed $\rho$) and  along $\vec r$ (changing $r$ at fixed $\phi$) means going in two mutually perpendicular directions.

Comment: thank you Svyatoslav, i am still processing your information, but for your answer i need change $\varphi$ and $r$ at same time right? Thank you

Comment: If you consider infinitesimal changes - $ds^2=\rho^2d\phi^2+dr^2$. If you go along some finite path on the cone, you have to define how you $\phi$ and $r$ change. Usually the curve on the surface is define by one parameter ($t$, for example), so you define $\rho(t)$ and $\phi(t)$. In this parametrization the path $L=\int ds=\int\sqrt{\rho^2d\phi^2+dr^2}=\int\sqrt{\rho^2(t)(d\phi/dt)^2+(dr/dt)^2}dt$, where $d\phi/dt$ and $dr/dt$ depend on $t$

Comment: Thanks a lot Svyatoslav!!!!

Comment: Corrected typos in the first post. Correct: draw the picture of the cone in polar coordinates in $R^3$. You have the $Z$ axis (this is the axis of symmetry of the cone); $\vec r$  lies on the cone, its coordinates are $  \vec r =(x,y,z)$. In polar system $x=r\sin\theta\cos\phi,y=r\sin\theta\cos\phi,z=r\cos\theta$. Angle $\theta$ is fixed, so you can travel on the cone just changing $r$ and $\phi$ - two independent variables. If you introduce $\rho^2=x^2+y^2=r^2\sin^2\theta$ which, at given $r$ and $\theta$ defines the circle on the cone. The element of length on this circle is $ds=\rho d\phi$

Comment: Svytoslav, i will write in my post your hint and you can look if what i do is fine? Please, Thank you so much!!

Comment: i finished, thank you Svyatoslav!!

Comment: Nice solution! Please correct one typo: should be: $dz^2=dr^2\cos^2\vartheta$, not $dz^2=dr^2\cos^2\varphi$, and you get $dx^2+dy^2+dz^2= dr^2 +r^2\sin^2\theta d\varphi^2$. Good luck!

Comment: is true, thanks again, best regards!!